# TypeError: ‘type’ object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I’m trying to get the function below to run. However I’m getting an error saying

```
TypeError: ‘type’ object is not subscriptable 




def dist(loc1: tuple[float], loc2: tuple[float]) -> float:
    dx = loc1[0] - loc2[0]
    dy = loc1[1] - loc2[1]
    return (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5
```

Comment: You need to show us how you are calling this.  There's nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: Upgrade Python, or use `typing.Tuple` instead of the builtin `tuple` in your type annotations.

Comment: I got the same error when doing `Queue[Any]`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, you can't say that it depends on how you call it when **it doesn't**. Running the above code alone produces the error in question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `typing.Tuple`, not the `tuple` class.

```
from typing import Tuple

def dist(loc1: Tuple[float], loc2: Tuple[float]) -> float:
    dx = loc1[0] - loc2[0]
    dy = loc1[1] - loc2[1]
    return (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5
dist((1,2),(2,1)) # output 1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: But this is not necessary in newer Python versions (at least from 3.9 onwards).

Comment: Nor is it true in older versions, because you could also use `from __future__ import annotations`. Or use a forward reference, by putting the hint in quotes.